# In what contexts are stable markets sub-optimal?

Tags: general-equilibrium, markets, commodities

My understanding is that market stability is a good thing, because it allows more reliable estimates of profits (revenues minus expenses) and expected return-on-investment related to new investments.

But in a recent article about Goldman Sachs' 4th quarter losses, with a 75% in commodities trading revenue as the greatest factor.

In the a BBC article, the firm reportedly framed the losses as:

> Goldman has blamed the problems on unusually calm markets, which can dampen demand from clients looking to take advantage of fluctuation.
>
> Executives have pledged to improve the business, which accounts for a large portion of the firm's overall revenue.
>
> Investors, however, are growing impatient. 
> <sub>SOURCE: [Goldman posts first quarterly loss in six years (BBC)](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-42723366)</sub>

See also: [Goldman’s Commodity Revenue Drops 75% to Lowest on Record](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-01-16/goldman-s-commodity-revenue-said-to-drop-75-to-lowest-on-record)

**- In which contexts are stable markets sub-optimal?**

---

*I'd also be interested in information how firms and governments can work to destabilize markets to create profit opportunities.*

Comment: I tried to add a ["stability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_stability) tag, but don't have the rep.